# Redis Search unable to query by text field

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a redis database where i store has hset entries with

1. A `MAC` address called *mid* in the form `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`
2. A `timestamp`
3. A geographical position called *position*
4. A text payload called *message*

I would like to be able to index those objects by the `mid`, the `timestamp` and the `position` (I will never query from information about the message).

This is the code for the schema of the index,

```
await client.ft.create(
            'idx:cits',
            {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    sortable: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            },
            {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
        )
```

And I insert new entries using

```
await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0:0:00.00:5e:00:53:af', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: '0,0',
        mid: '00:00:5e:00:53:af',
        message: 'payload'
    })
```

I can perfectly query by `timestamp` and `position` both in the javascript code using

```js
await client.ft.search('idx:cits', '@timestamp:[100 19123180] @position:[0 0 10 km]')
```

and in the redis-cli using

```bash
FT.SEARCH idx:cits "@timestamp:[100 19123180] @position:[0 0 10 km]"
```

But it does not work when querying by the mid field.

I have tried both

```js
await client.ft.search('idx:cits', '@mid:"00:00:5e:00:53:af"')
```

and in redis-cli

```bash
FT.SEARCH idx:cits idx:cits '@mid:"00:00:5e:00:53:af"'
```

I have also tried exchanging the " and the ' as well as eliminating them to see if it worked without any result.

I have also tried storing the mac addresses as `XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX` instead of `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` and did not result either.

I have also seen that it will not work for `00:00:5e:00:53:af` but instead it works for `ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff`.

I'm not sure why I am not able to query by the mid, I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Here is an example script

```js
const { createClient, SchemaFieldTypes } = require('redis')

const client = createClient()

async function start(client) {
    await client.connect()
    try {
        // We only want to sort by these 3 values
        await client.ft.create(
            'idx:cits',
            {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    sortable: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            },
            {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message === 'Index already exists') {
            console.log('Skipping index creation as it already exists.')
        } else {
            console.error(e)
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }

    await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0:0:00.00.5e.00.53.af', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: '0,0',
        mid: '00.00.5e.00.53.af',
        message: 'payload'
    })
    await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0.001:0.001:ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: '0.000001,0.000001',
        mid: 'ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff',
        message: 'payload'
    })

    const results = await client.ft.search('idx:cits', '@mid:00.00.5e.00.53.af')
    console.log(results)

    await client.quit()
}
start(client)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TEXT type in RediSearch is intended for full-text search—i.e. text meant for humans to read and not meant for computers to parse. So, it removes and doesn't search for things like punctuation—i.e. periods, colons, commas, etc.—and common words like *a*, *and*, or *the*.

You want to use a [TAG](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/#tag-filters) type instead. You can think of these like a tag cloud on a blog post. A TAG field should contain a comma-separated string of values—the tags. If there's just a single value, it's just a CSV of one.

To create an index that uses a TAG field, do this:

```js
await client.ft.create('idx:cits', {
  mid: { type: SchemaFieldTypes.TAG },
  timestamp: { type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC, sortable: true },
  position: { type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO }
})
```

To search a TAG field, use curly braces. Like this:

```js
await client.ft.search('idx:cits', '@mid:{00:00:5e:00:53:af}')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I should note that when querying, you should add `\\ ` before the `:` as it acts as a stopword and gives syntax error. So it would be `@mid:{00\\:00\\:5e\\:00\\:53\\:af}`

Comment: Good to know! I didn't think that `:` would do that. I know it's good practice to escape spaces as well since TAGs like `Class A` have the stopword of `A` in it. RediSearch will give you a syntax error in that case.